# array of multiple UIViews without stacking

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

it seems normally if you have multiple UIViews, you stack them by using insertSubview at index.

```
self.view.insertSubview(testUIView, atIndex: 1)
```

but i want to use a single UIView.

i have an array of different UIViews

```
  let plotUIViews: [UIView] = [testView(), FaceView()]
```

here is testView

```
import UIKit
class testView: UIView {
  override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    var greenView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 100))
    greenView.backgroundColor=UIColor.greenColor()
  }
}
```

i have a generic UIView

```
@IBOutlet var testUIView: UIView!
```

and would like to do this, it is a bit perl-ish rather than swift-ish (to save memory of having all views drawn on each layer then manipulating the index)

```
self.testUIView?.removeFromSuperview()
self.testUIView = nil

switch plotValue{
case 0:
  self.testUIview=plotUIViews[0]
case 1:
  self.testUIview=plotUIViews[1]
case 2:
      self.testUIview=plotUIViews[2]
etc
    }

    self.view.insertSubview(testUIView, atIndex: 2)
```

nothing shows in testUIView

thanks for any help or pointers.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Why that last code doesn't work (assume that you mean `[UIView]` not `[String]`). If you have multiple view, you don't have to show them all at once. Just add them to the view hierarchy when you want them on screen.

Comment: thanks i fixed the typos  also posted the error i get this error .

Comment: So, that's because `plotUIViews` is actually an array of `String`! How do you plan to get the views from those names?

Comment: thanks updated array and error code

Comment: replace self.testUIView inside insertSubview method or _testUIView.

Comment: What is the error now?

Comment: i tried this `self.view.insertSubview(self.testUIView, atIndex: 2)` but still get nothing to display

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is to only display one of your plot views at a time. So, remove the prior plot view, if there is one, before showing the new one:

```
self.testUIView?.removeFromSuperview()
self.testUIView = nil
switch plotValue {
  ...
}
self.view.insertSubview(testUIView, atIndex: 2)
```

Comment: yes, i modified code as you suggested but there is no display.